# SQL Query to return records with and without sub-records

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that I'm trying to query, Clients, Employees and Commissions, roughly laid out as below: -

**Clients**

```
ID - Code - Name
```

**Employees**

```
ID - Code - Name
```

**Commissions**

```
ID - ClientCode - EmployeeCode - Percent
```

Now, the commissions table has multiple records per client/employee defining the % commission for employee's when working for specific clients, but each clients commissions entry will always sum to 100%
For example: -

```
CL001 - EMP001 -  50.00

CL001 - EMP002 -  50.00

CL002 - EMP001 -  75.00

CL002 - EMP002 -  25.00

CL003 - EMP001 - 100.00
```

However, not every client from the Clients table has an entry in the Commissions table (those with no default commission set).

What I need to retrieve is a record of every client, detailing the commissions set against it. However, I need the results to include clients that do not have any commission defined, and so far i've been unable to get what I need.

So I guess my question is, does this seem plausible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT Clients.ID, Clients.Code, Clients.Name, Commission.Percent
FROM Clients
LEFT JOIN Commission ON Commission.ClientCode = Clients.Code
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN! Simple as that! i ideally should learn more SQL! Thank you both very much for your quick replies!